# OpenERP: get the database and show it in form

Tags: python, odoo

I do a project about Timesheet in OpenERP. I have this problem:
this is x_luong table.

```
class x_luong(osv.osv):
     _name = 'x_luong'
     _description = 'Luong'

     _columns = {'name': fields.many2one('x_nhanvien', 'Mã nhân viên', size=10, required='1'),
                 'ma_luong': fields.integer('ma luong', size=10, required='1'),
                 'giolam': fields.float('Giờ làm', size=100, required='1'),
                 'giolamthuc': fields.char('Gio lam thuc te', size=5, required='1'),
                 'time_in': fields.char('Gio vào', size=20),
                 'time_out' :fields.char('Gio về', size=20),
                 'state' :fields.selection([('dangnhap','Đẳng nhập.'),('rave','Ra về')]),
                 'test': fields.integer('Kiem tra', size=20),
                 'phutvao': fields.integer('Phut vao ', size=20),
                 'phutra': fields.integer('phut ra', size=20),
                }
     _defaults = {'state':'dangnhap',
                 }
```

and this some function in it:

**this 2 function mean get time when the staff sign_in or sign_out the system**:

```
def get_timein(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
    obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
    timein = str(datetime.now())
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'time_in':timein }, context=context)
    return 1

def get_timeout(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
    obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
    timeout = str(datetime.now())
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'time_out':timeout }, context=context)
    return 1
```

**and this 2 function for button sign_in and sign_out:**

```
def cho_dangnhap(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
    self.pool.get('x_luong').write(cr,uid,ids,{'state':'dangnhap'})
    self.get_timein(cr,uid,ids)
    return 1

def cho_rave(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
    self.pool.get('x_luong').write(cr,uid,ids,{'state':'rave'})
    self.get_timeout(cr,uid,ids)
    self.tinh_thoigian(cr,uid,ids)
    self.insert(cr,uid,ids)
```

**function tinh_thoigian mean cut the string time for get ... hour or min for calculation**

```
def _thoigianlam(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
    obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
    hour_den = int(obj.time_in[12:13])
    hour_di = int(obj.time_out[12:13])
    min_den = int(obj.time_in[15:16])
    min_di = int(obj.time_out[15:16])
    gl = int(hour_di)-int(hour_den)
    pl = min_di-min_den
    thucte = str(gl)+':'+pl
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'giolam':gl }, context=context)
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'giolamthuc':thucte }, context=context)
    return 1
```

and last function insert() get ma_luong(i think this same the primary key in sql) and giolam(the hour of the staff work in company), time_in, time_out and this is function insert()

```
def insert(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
    obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
    values = {'ma_luong':obj.name.id,
             'giolam':obj.giolam,
             'time_in':time_in,
             'time_out':time_out,

    self.pool.get('x_giolam').create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
```

with this function i want insert data in table x_giolam because when the staff sign in or sign out the system in day ... the data of it with save in this table and a other day when they do it again it with save it again ... and last month if you want calculation about salary of them you just select ma_luong=ma_luong(of table x_luong) and this table x_giolam:

```
class x_giolam(osv.osv):
    _name = 'x_giolam'
    _description = 'Gio Lam'
    _columns = {'name': fields.integer('Lọai',size=64,required="true"),
                'giolam' : fields.float('Gio lam',size=64,required="True"),
                'time_in': fields.char('Gio vào',size=20),
                'time_out' :fields.char('Gio về',size=20),         
                }
```

and i have 3 question with my project:

1) function insert have aerror:

```
AttributeError: 'browse_record_list' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can i fix it ??? i data of it is save in table x_giolam
2) how can i select many row of table x_giolam which of thte employee' own.. give me some example about this function
3) how i can organization field.Xml when i show rows in

Sorry for your troubles because it is so long ... but i hope every body in here can help me. Python and open Erp so difference with c++ or c#. And this my project"research and write a module timesheet with OpenErp" of me and next week is deadline.
English of me not good, i'm sory about it!!!
Thanks!!

Comment: You might get better answers if you moved your questions to the top. Don't make people read through all the details before telling them your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help with your first question. The problem is in this code:

```
def insert(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
                obj=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
                values={'ma_luong':obj.name.id,
```

The error message was like this:

> AttributeError: 'browse_record_list' object has no attribute 'name'

If you call `orm.browse()` with a list of ids, you will get back a list of browse records. You then have to enumerate through the list, or get a single entry from the list to work with.

For example:

```
for luong in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
    print luong.name
```

Or:

```
luongs = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
luong = luongs[0]
print luong.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at the standard `hr_attendance` module and go on from there?
For your model, the `name` is a reserved field name, so it would be best to keep it as a`char`. Try that change and see if it solves your error message.

For the other two questions, I think you should try to rephrase them a little better...

Answer (score 0):

The type of obj is list of records, so for browse the list of records, you must define a one element. 
in your case, you can type : obj[0].giolam --> for the giolam of the first record of obj.
forgive me for my bad english